# Как здесь работает цикл?

Tags: java

Учусь java и не могу понять как работает цикл в этой программе?
Как она выходит на ответ 15?
Объясните пожалуйста пошагово, что-то не понимаю

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i;
        int sum = 0;

        for (i = 1; i <= 5; sum = sum+i, i++);
        System.out.println("Сумма: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sum = sum + i, i++` ну вот же

Comment: Вот вручную обсчитываю цикл: - у меня выходит ответ - 14. А программа выводит 15

Comment: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 3 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 6 + 4 + 5 = 10 + 5 = 15`. Пора знание математики подтянуть

Comment: Я просто в одном месте арифметически ошибся - спасибо за ответ)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По сути, представленный алгоритм – арифметическая прогрессия.

Всего происходит пять итераций цикла. Каждый раз обновляются две переменные – `sum` и `i`.
Здесь происходит присвоение очередного значения: `sum = sum + i`:

1. sum = 0 (sum) + 1 (i)
2. sum = 1 (sum) + 2 (i)
3. sum = 3 (sum) + 3 (i)
4. sum = 6 (sum) + 4 (i)
5. sum = 10 (sum) + 5 (i)

[Тут](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.6.php) можете закрепить знания циклов, если потребуется (в том числе рассматривается изменение нескольких переменных в контексте цикла).

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в `sum = sum+i`

Первая итерация: 0 = 0 + 1      В итоге: `sum` = 1

Вторая итерация: 1 = 1 + 2      В итоге: `sum` = 3

Третья итерация: 3 = 3 + 3      В итоге: `sum` = 6

Четвертая итерация: 6 = 6 + 4   В итоге: `sum` = 10

Пятая итерация: 10 = 10 + 5     В итоге: `sum` = 15

Далее т.к. `i` уже равно 6 цикл прекращается и `System.out.println()` выводит последнее значение `sum` из пятой итерации